# ReturnFormat row when POSTing CFAJAX request

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I'm struggling with the setQueryFormat() call to an AJAX-function in CF9. I have CFM-File that looks like so:

```
  <div id="div1" onclick="callfkt1('POST');" style="cursor:pointer;">POST</div>
  <div id="div2" onclick="callfkt1('GET');" style="cursor:pointer;">GET</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function callfkt1(sHTTPMethod) {
    var oTester001=new CTester001();
    oTester001.setCallbackHandler(function(result) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
    oTester001.setErrorHandler(function(err, msg) {
     alert(err + ': ' + msg);
    });
    oTester001.setHTTPMethod(sHTTPMethod);
    oTester001.setQueryFormat('column');
    oTester001.fkt1();
   }
  </script>
```

Tester001.cfc contains the following:

```
 <cfcomponent >
 <cffunction name="fkt1" returntype="query" access="remote">
  <cfquery name="local.queries.qry1" datasource="brdwr">
   SELECT url_id, url
   FROM urls
  </cfquery>
  <cfreturn local.queries.qry1>
 </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

When I call the JavaScript function With parameter 'GET' the result is returned in query format 'column' which means it contains a ROWCOUNT member that stores the number of records returned from the query. Using request method 'POST' the recordset is returned in format 'row' without ROWCOUNT member. Have you experienced this? Do you limit to GETing CFAJAX request?

Best.

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing your CFC so that you explicitly declare how you want the JSON returned by using the serilizeJson function:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_a-b_3.html

As the second argument of the function, you can set serializeQueryByColumns to True, so that it will serialize the data as a WDDX query format, which is what the setQueryFormat("column") is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried two things, both worked. If I cfreturn SerializeJSON(qry) the returntype is no longer a query but a string. If I put another DeserializeJSON() around and change returntype to any the client receives the desired format. The second solution is much more simple: I set url.queryFormat to column in the cffunction and everything works as intended. Looks like Coldfusion does not respect the POSTed queryformat.

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer, do know that when the row format is used, you still get the same data. It's in a different format, but you still get *all* the data. You just have to work with it differently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got a code from a coworker using the column format and a GET request on the client side. I thought I simply change it to POST but that didn't work.